# tinymce onkeyup call jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, onkeyup, onkeypress

I have a problem with my tinymce integration. 
Here is my code and my not working solution:

```
<div class="mcebox">
    <label>Text </label>
    <textarea name="text" class="ta_cprofi mceEditorblick" id="textcontent"></textarea>
    <div id="preview"></div>
</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode: "specific_textareas",
        editor_selector: "mceEditorblick",
        theme: "advanced",

        paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste: true,
        theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold",
        theme_advanced_buttons2: "", 
        theme_advanced_buttons3: "",

        setup: function(ed) {
            ed.onKeyUp.add(function() {
                alert("Hello");
            });
        },
    });

    function blumieka() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "inc/admin/blumieka/ajax_modules/ajax_ads.php",
            data: "load=blumieka&text=" + document.getElementById("textcontent").value,

            success: function(html) {
                $("#preview").html(html)
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

The alert message works perfectly.
Now I want to replace the alert with the jquery function "blumieka". 
I have tried this:

```
setup: function(ed) {
    ed.onKeyUp.add(function() {
        blumieka();
    });
},
```

But this doesn't work... 
What is my error?

I use tinymce Version 3.
I just need tinymce only because I have to set some text in the textarea to bold.

Thank you for helping me. I am desperate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the issue your having is `document.getElementById("textcontent").value`. This doesn't get the value of the editor. It is just blank text. To get the actual HTML content from the editor you need to use `tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()`.

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode: "specific_textareas",
    editor_selector: "mceEditorblick",
    theme: "advanced",

    paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste: true,
    theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold",
    theme_advanced_buttons2: "", 
    theme_advanced_buttons3: "",

    setup: function(ed) {
        ed.onKeyUp.add(function() {
            blumieka();
        });
    },
});

function blumieka() {
    //get the actual content from editor
    var content = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "inc/admin/blumieka/ajax_modules/ajax_ads.php",
        data: "load=blumieka&text=" + content,

        success: function(html) {
            $("#preview").html(html)
        }
    });
}
```

Here is a working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PalinDrome555/kg5ew6hy/)